# Is this question suitable here?

Tags: support, on-topic

I came from the general meta site [with this question in mind](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279696/where-to-ask-why-a-file-can-be-a-valid-jpg-and-rar-simultaneously/279697#279697):

> I know I can build a .rar file with regular method or programs, and append it to an image by using a command such as `cat img.jpg myfile.rar > img.jpg` and when opening the image, the image will be displayed as before. But I can also open the image with WinRAR or a software alike (like `unrar e img.jpg`). How is possible that the rar file is recognized inside the jpg image, instead of rejected as not being an appropriate file format?

Is that question suitable here?

Comment: Looks good to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's about file formats that are related to general computing. You've explained the setup well and it's clear what you're asking. Therefore, you can ask it here.

Comment: An error message appeared to me telling I can post once every 40 minutes! What can I do? I am trying to post in the main site and the only question I did was this (meta) question.

Comment: I imagine that message means you can only post one question every 40 minutes. Wait a while, then you'll be able to ask it.

Comment: Will have to wait then. Pretty weird, never happened to me in other SE sites.

Comment: If you can only post 1 question ever 40 minutes it means some of your past questions have not been well received.  Be sure this question is extremely high quality from a clarity, grammatical, and research perspective.